# How to run a executable before showing application main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, process

In my WPF application I want to run an executable in `App.cs` before the WPF window gets shown and wait for the process to exit before starting the WPF application..

What's the best way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(@"exe file path");
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Dispose();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, All works good, BUT
when i close my wpf application, on exit it throws a dis assembly 
Exception from 14:03:11.8556778
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Namespace.App' cannot run multiple times.
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()

Comment: Add p.Dispose(); then run again.

Comment: Same, "app cannot run multiple times."
  Process p = Process.Start(info.FullName);
                   p.WaitForExit();
                   p.Dispose();
 this.Run(new MainWindow());

Comment: Thanks for the help
base.OnStartup(e); doesnt make the wpf window to showup
if i will add Run() it will tell me the same exception

any more ideas :p ?

Comment: You shouldn't use Run() in WPF application. OnStartup raised before  startup window(mainwindow) show, thus use exactly this code without calling Run()